# angular-cli + mvn : cannot launch build

Tags: angular, maven, angular-cli

I generated my angular 2 project with angular-cli.
I cannot upgrade to angular 4 because of project and customer constraints.

I try to use frontend-maven-plugin to compile my angular app with maven, but when I launch mvn clean install, the build script fails.

I got the error :

> [ERROR]
>   ..pathToProject/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/schema-class-factory.js:34
>   [ERROR]             result.push(...indices); [ERROR]
>    ^^^ [ERROR]  [ERROR] SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... [ERROR]     at
>   exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16) [ERROR]     at Module._compile
>   (module.js:373:25) [ERROR]     at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:416:10) [ERROR]     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>   [ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) [ERROR]     at
>   Module.require (module.js:353:17) [ERROR]     at require
>   (internal/module.js:12:17) [ERROR]     at Object.
>   (..pathToProject/node_modules/@ngtools/json-schema/src/index.js:3:30)
>   [ERROR]     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) [ERROR]     at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) [ERROR]  [ERROR] npm
>   ERR! Linux 4.4.0-92-generic [ERROR] npm ERR! argv
>   "..pathToProject/node/node"
>   "..pathToProject/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js"
>   "run-script" "build" [ERROR] npm ERR! node v4.6.0 [ERROR] npm ERR! npm
>   v2.15.9 [ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE [ERROR] npm ERR! hsmt@0.0.0
>   build: `ng build` [ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 1 [ERROR] npm ERR! 
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the hsmt@0.0.0 build script 'ng build'.
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hsmt package,
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! not with npm itself. [ERROR] npm ERR! Tell the author
>   that this fails on your system: [ERROR] npm ERR!     ng build [ERROR]
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with: [ERROR] npm ERR!     npm bugs hsmt

My pom :

```
<build>
     <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
     <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.5</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>install node and npm</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>
           <npmVersion>v2.15.9</npmVersion>
         </configuration>
       </execution>

       <execution>
         <id>build</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>npm</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
         </configuration>
         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
       </execution>

     </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "hsmt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prod" : "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "prebuild": "npm install"
  },
```

Comment: `<nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>` :-o. current lts is 6.11.2. Check what version you are using outside of maven and stick to it in your pom.xml. BTW Is this error only appearing in maven ? (I assume yes)

Comment: Great this is working with node v6.11.2 :) (and this is indeed installed version on my computer) I've tried to upgrade  npm as well but seems that it cannot find v3.10.10 on https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/ Do you know which repo should I use?

Comment: I use npm `3.8.6` with node `6.11.0` on my maven project I guess you can use both node `6.11.2` and npm `3.8.6`...

Comment: It cannot find this version either : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.5:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project hsmt-angular: Could not download npm: Got error code 500 from the server. -> [Help 1]

Did you use a specific repository?

Comment: Try without the "v" (extracted from my `pom.xml`:                     `<nodeVersion>v6.11.0</nodeVersion><npmVersion>3.8.6</npmVersion>`)

Comment: awesome, this is working even with 3.10.10  :) many thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of nodejs and npm, you just need to switch to the version you are using outside of maven.

in a terminal run these commands:

```
npm --version
node --version
```

on my computer, these commands outputs `v6.11.2` for nodejs and `3.10.10` for npm so the `pom.xml` should look like this :

```xml
<nodeVersion>v6.11.2</nodeVersion>
<npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need a specific frontend plugin for that task.

If in your environment the you're able to run npm run build than you can use the exec-maven-plugin with something like this:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install npm dependencies</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
              <executable>npm</executable>
              <commandlineArgs>install</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>build webapp</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
              <executable>npm</executable>
              <commandlineArgs>run build</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is portability, other developers need to manage node and npm versions by hand. Which is a real pain and can lead to unpredictable behavior. the frontend plugin is great for that because it manages the node version for you.

Comment: If you use package-lock.json/npm-shrinkwrap.json you shouldn't have version problem. The main thing to lock are packages not node version. But I get your point.